# A U.S. patent is to issue on a future date; is there any way to view the patent prior to the date of issue?

Tags: search, patent-services, patent-search, notice, issue

A patent is provided (i) Notice of Allowance, (ii) Notice of Allowance and Fee(s) Due, or (iii) Issue Notification by the USPTO with a date set in the future.

Is there a way for the first named inventor in a *pro se* case to view the patent to issue or a copy of the text to be included, for e.g., to verify any typos or other issues?

If so, what is it?

What if there is an applicant represented by patent attorneys; do they receive a copy or have otherwise access to the patent to issue or a copy of the text to be included prior to the issue date?

If so, what is it?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think so. Things can go wrong in the production of the final text which very often involves incorporating amendments. The first you see the final version is the day of issue.

The best you can do to assure an accurate patent is to carefully check it after issue and get a Certificate of Correction issued. There are services you can use that are very meticulous about finding discrepancies.